# What is the beta function of $\mathrm{SO}(N)$ Yang-Mills?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, group-theory, renormalization, yang-mills

What is the beta function of $\mathrm{SO}(N)$-Yang-Mills? I know that $\mathrm{SO}(4)\cong\mathrm{SU}(2)\times \mathrm{SU}(2)$ and that the beta function of $\mathrm{SU}(2)$  is well known.

Comment: [tried google?](https://web2.ph.utexas.edu/~vadim/Classes/2019f/qcd-beta.pdf#page=20)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question is quite ambiguous. I gather you are asking for the β-function to one loop of the *pure* gauge theory, and not indirectly asking about the representation theory implications for fermions and scalars in arbitrary representations of *SO(N)*, a heftier problem.

You presumably are comfortable with the $\mathfrak{su}(2)$
result,
$$
\beta=\frac{\partial g}{\partial \ln \mu}=-\frac{g^3}{16\pi^2}\frac{11}{3} C_2( \mathfrak{su}(2))$$
for adjoint quadratic Casimir eigenvalues $C_2( \mathfrak{su}(2))$ $= C_2( \mathfrak{so}(3))=2$ and tried to reconcile  it with the $N>2$ formula,
$$C_2( \mathfrak{so}(N ))=N-2,$$
without success.

Note it is quite consistent with $ \mathfrak{so}(6)\cong\mathfrak{su}(4)  \mapsto  4$; but you are perhaps confused by  $ \mathfrak{so}(4)\cong\mathfrak{su}(2)\oplus \mathfrak{su}(2) \cong\mathfrak{so}(3)\oplus \mathfrak{so}(3) \mapsto  2$?

The point is to focus on the action of the
direct-product group *SO(4)* on its 6-dimensional adjoint representation; what 6×6 (*not* 9×9  !) matrices will act on it, to be squared?  A direct *sum* structure of the two factor subgroup generators--so, if you considered doubling the Casimir of $\mathfrak{so}(3)$, think again. That is to say, The 6 generators sit in the 6×6 adjoint rep matrix completely disjoint: 3 in the upper left 3×3 block, and the other 3 in the lower-right 3×3 block. Squaring all 6 of them and summing yields the 6-dimensional identity, with, manifestly, a factor of 2=1×(1+1) multiplying it.

The easiest way for you to visualize this structure is to think of the two *SO(3)* s in the direct product as completely different gauge groups, with different couplings, *g* and *g'*, respectively. The respective *so(3)* β-functions are identical, and so it is up to you to blind yourself to the ' of the second factor group and still have the same β-function. You never combine the two couplings in any way, except in the fermion couplings, direct sum above, in a notation respectful of their subspaces.

- It might be helpful, perhaps, to recall Pauli's 1926  epic quantization of the Hydrogen atom, (Pauli, W,  Über das Wasserstoffspektrum vom Standpunkt der neuen Quantenmechanik *Zeitschrift für Physik A Hadrons and nuclei*  **36**(5), 336-363.).

Comment: I know that the representation is reducible. And that the Lorentz generators can be decomposed into anti-self dual and self-dual parts, generated by the t' Hooft matrices and that it induces a hodge star decomposition on the space of one and two-forms over an orientable smooth manifold with dimension 4. Does it mean that C(so(4))=1/N×N +1/N×N?

Comment: I've no idea what your N's mean in your alarming comment. If you are trying to understand so(4), its reps are already reduced, not just reducible.  I much fear references to the structure of the Lorentz group can only throw every possible confusion pot on the fire. I added classificatory statements in my answer.